# How to make an attribute for an erd entity that isn't always there

Tags: entity-relationship, erd

I'm making an ERD that includes the relationship "entity tourist stays at entity residence". Entity residence could be a hotel or tourist camp. Each of those have their own specific attributes. How do I specify this in an ERD diagram?

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you mean that there could be 0 tourists at the residence?

in that case the relation should simply be something like:

tourist 0...* residence  (there can be 0 -> infinite tourist at a residence)
or
tourist 0...X residence (x being the max number of tourists the residence MAX can hold, eg there can be 0 -> 10 tourists at a residence)